# How to compute precision, recall , F1score for a simple IR system that returns answers to questions?

Tags: metrics, information-retrieval, precision-recall

I have developed an IR system that returns an answer to a user question by applying some searching techniques in a DB. I would like to evaluate its performance with f1-Score but since the possible states of the result could be either CORRECT or INCORRECT answer i get a bit confused on what would the TP,TN,FP,FN be. Any ideas? or maybe a more suitable test?

Comment: are your answers of yes/no type or they are natural language text? if text, would you consider your questions to be of type where you would expect multiple correct answers? if not text, and questions have only one possible answer, you don't need to measure recall.. simply measure precision...

Comment: it returns one possible answer text. Are there any other metrics for this kind of systems?

Comment: one common metric is the MRR if you return a ranked list of answers.. the reciprocal rank of the first relevant answer is a good measure that prefers systems that retrieve relevant answers towards better ranks... recall is difficult to compute for QA systems, because for measuring recall one needs to compile a list of relevant answers possible for a question...